# build failed in gitlab.com using default pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab's autoDevOps integrated with Google Cloud Kubernetes. I've already setup a project in my group and everything is working great. But when I tried setup another project on this group, the build just fails.

I would like to know if I can find any detailed log on Gitlab to clarify this problem, ideally more detailed than:

> error checking context: 'syntax error in pattern'

I've already validated my Dockerfile and already have a project configured on Gitlab.

Here's the error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your question and check the answer to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .dockerignore file was wrong. I notice that the path separator ("/") was wrong. The correct is ("\") and eveything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rodrigo Celebrone's answer is backwards, you want to replace backslashes ("\") with forward slashes ("/")